# Extract/ Eliminate duplicate text in imacros

Tags: javascript, regex, split, match, imacros

I'm Extracting data from [this](http://www.magicbricks.com/property-for-sale/residential-real-estate?bedroom=1&proptype=Multistorey-Apartment,Builder-Floor-Apartment,Penthouse,Studio-Apartment&cityName=Thane&BudgetMin=5-Lacs&BudgetMax=20-Lacs) link
by using this

```
TAG POS=2 TYPE=a ATTR=CLASS:property-sticky-link&&TXT:* EXTRACT=TXT
```

But this is giving me

```
BHK Apartmentfor sale in1 BHK Apartmentfor sale inKalyan1 BHK Apartment1 BHK Apartmentfor sale in1 BHK Apartmentfor sale inKalyan1 BHK Apartmentfor sale in1 BHK Apartmentfor sale inKalyan1 BHK Apartmentfor sale in1 BHK Apartmentfor sale inKalyan1 BHK Apartment1 BHK Apartmentfor sale in1 BHK Apartmentfor sale inKalyan1 BHK Apartmentfor sale in1 BHK Apartmentfor sale inKalyan1 BHK Apartmentfor sale in1 BHK Apartmentfor sale inKalyan690 sqft
```

but what I want is just `1 BHK Apartmentfor sale inKalyan` only once

so tried this `SET !VAR1 EVAL("var s=\"{{!EXTRACT}}\"; s.split(' ')[-7];")`
And

```
SET !VAR1 EVAL("'{{!EXTRACT}}'.match(/?BHK.: (\\d+)/)[-7];")
```

But These aren't working.

Any idea on how to go about this.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I'd rather extract the parts from individual tags:

```
TAG XPATH=".//body/descendant::div[@class='propDBlock'][1]/descendant::a[@class='property-sticky-link']/h3" EXTRACT=txt
```

Result: "1 BHK Apartment"

```
TAG XPATH=".//body/descendant::div[@class='propDBlock'][1]/descendant::h3/span[@class='noWrapLocality']" EXTRACT=txt
```

Result: "for sale in"

```
TAG XPATH=".//body/descendant::div[@class='propDBlock'][1]/descendant::span[@class='localityFirst']" EXTRACT=txt
```

Result: "Ambernath"

```
TAG XPATH=".//body/descendant::div[@class='propDBlock'][1]/descendant::b[@class='areaValue']" EXTRACT=txt
```

Result: "600 sqft"

...then you can use them separately (e.g. in different columns of csv file) or concatenate them via javascript.

You can also use [{{!LOOP}}] instead of [number] in XPATH.